# In Django, How to change only specific parameters on url in template using GET form?

Tags: python, html, django, web, django-forms

```
<div class="md-form my-0">

              <form action="{% url 'core:home' %}" method="GET" >

                  <input name="priceMin" type="number"  class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Min" 
                  aria-label = "Search">
              </form>

</div>
```

I want to change only one parameter from my url. For example, if my current url looks like "home/?category=KN&priceMin=50",

after form i want to get "home/?category=KN&priceMin=30"

but i got "home/?priceMin=30".

My other variables are erased, i want only 1 parameter to change, what should i do ?    (My Url is suitable for that format so dont mind changing it)

Comment: There's not really an elegant way to do what you're describing. For it to be part of your querystring from a GET form submission, that parameter needs to be part of your form. You could add `category` to your form as a hidden input and use if/else in your template to determine what the category is when the template is rendered.

Comment: if you're filtering against a number of parameters, I'd really recommend django-filter https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/# could save you a lot of time

Comment: @DragonBobZ thanks i will try that!

Comment: Okay, cool. I think little solutions like this are good to play with and figure out, but I'd agree with RHSSmith159; unless this is a toy or a just personal project where you know the complexity won't grow, it might be a good idea to look into something like `django-filter` that solves this problem very well.